# How to define common query params in Redux Toolkit Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

All the endpoints of the API I'm working on, require the same set of query parameters. The user **must** select these parameters before making requests to endpoints.

*Examples of endpoints*

```
/api/resource-1?param1=valueA&param2=valueB&param3=valueC
/api/resource-2?param1=valueA&param2=valueB&param3=valueC
```

Selected values are saved on the Redux Store. I'd like to customize my baseQuery to append these query params to API URL automatically. I'm searching something in `fetchBaseQuery` that works similar to `prepareHeaders` allowing to customize the query URL.

*hypothetical code*

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: baseUrl,
  // THIS PROPERTY DOES NOT EXISTS
  prepareUrl: (url, { getState }) => {
    const param1 = (getState() as AppState).config.param;
    if (param1) {
      url.searchParams.append('param1', param1);
    }
    return url;
  },
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = (getState() as AppState).auth.token;
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return headers;
  },
});
```

I read how to [implement a custom base query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#implementing-a-custom-basequery) but I don't want to lose the behavior provided by `fetchBaseQuery`.

Is there something like the `prepareUrl` property that allows to customize the request URL? Should I implement a custom base query? What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already on the right page in the docs. The trick is to not write a completely new baseQuery, but to wrap a custom baseQuery "around" the existing implementation. [This examples shows how to do that to get a dynamic baseUrl](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#constructing-a-dynamic-base-url-using-redux-state), which should be very close to what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom query code I ended up with:

```
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { FetchArgs } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/fetchBaseQuery'
import { BaseQueryApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/baseQueryTypes';
import { RootState } from '../store';

const customQuery = async (args: string | FetchArgs, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}) => {
    args = appendQueryStringParam(args, "Source", "Desktop");
    args = appendQueryStringParam(args, "LoginToken", "XYZ");

    return await fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://example.com/api' })(args, api, extraOptions);
}

function appendQueryStringParam(args: string | FetchArgs, key: string, value: string): string | FetchArgs {
    let urlEnd = typeof args === 'string' ? args : args.url;

    if (urlEnd.indexOf('?') < 0)
        urlEnd += '?';
    else
        urlEnd += '&';

    urlEnd += `${key}=${value}`;

    return typeof args === 'string' ? urlEnd : { ...args, url: urlEnd };
}

export default customQuery;
```